# Netty 4.0 Client/Server Freezes on Connection

Tags: java, netty

Well i was working ok with Netty 3 but i wanted to work with Netty 4, i converted the code and got all of this below, im not sure if its a server issue and client issue in the code because it doesnt tell me, not even the source of the error, i also tried sending no data to the server and it still did it, i can not interact with the client but from tests it is making the application take up more ram very slowly and i am only sending strings that are not even 40 chars long

MecaCoreConnector (Client):

```
import io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelOption;
import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel;
import io.netty.handler.codec.DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder;
import io.netty.handler.codec.Delimiters;
import io.netty.handler.codec.LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder;
import io.netty.handler.codec.string.StringDecoder;
import io.netty.handler.codec.string.StringEncoder;
import main.java.net.meca.thecheatgamer1.CryptionUtils;
import main.java.net.mecalib.logger.Logger;

public class MecaCoreConnector {

    private static CryptionUtils cryption = new CryptionUtils();

    protected static UserAuthenticationData userdata;

    private ChannelFuture ch;

    private final static String host = "secret";
    private final static int port = secret;

    private static MecaCoreConnector MecaConnection;

    public MecaCoreConnector() {
        MecaConnection = this;
    }

    public void init() throws InterruptedException {
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();

            bootstrap.group(workerGroup);
            bootstrap.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
            bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

            bootstrap.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                public void initChannel(SocketChannel channel) throws Exception {
                    channel.pipeline().addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
                    channel.pipeline().addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder());
                    channel.pipeline().addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());
                    channel.pipeline().addLast("handler", new MecaCoreConnectorAdapter());
                }
            });
            ch = bootstrap.connect(host, port).sync();
            ch.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }

    public void login(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        ch.channel().write("Username:" + username + " Password:" + cryption.getEncrpytedString(password) + "\r\n");
        ch.channel().flush();
    }

    public void fetchAdvertisments() {
        //channel.write("request: advertisments");
    }

    public static MecaCoreConnector getMecaConnection() {
        return MecaConnection;
    }

    public static UserAuthenticationData getUserData() {
        return userdata;
    }
}
```

MecaCoreConnectionAdapter (Client):

```
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import main.java.net.meca.launcher.gui.LoginClient;
import main.java.net.meca.launcher.gui.panel.home.Advertisment;
import main.java.net.mecalib.logger.Logger;

public class MecaCoreConnectorAdapter extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    public static MecaCoreConnectorAdapter instance;

    public enum Command {
        // Creation
        createFile, createFolder,

        // Deletion
        removeFile, removeFolder,

        // Window Instructors
        closeWindow, openWindow, sendAlert, sendMessage,

        // User Instructors
        createUser
    }

    public enum LoginDataType {
        NumericID, UUID, GameUUID, AvatarLink, Rank
    }

    public enum DataType {
        // Common Types
        file, folder, zipExtraction,

        // Advertisments
        downloadAdvertisment, deleteAdvertisment
    }

    /*
     * Stored Data
     */

    public static Advertisment[] ads;
    public String imageURLs;
    public String imageLinks;
    public String viewChances;

    /*
     * 
     */

    public MecaCoreConnectorAdapter() {
        instance = this;
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object e) {
        if (String.valueOf(e).contains("createUser")) {
            MecaCoreConnector.getMecaConnection().userdata = new UserAuthenticationData();
        } else if (String.valueOf(e).contains("NumericID")) {
            MecaCoreConnector.getMecaConnection().getUserData().setNumericID(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(e).replace("NumericID ", "")));
        } else if (String.valueOf(e).contains("UUID")) {
            MecaCoreConnector.getMecaConnection().getUserData().setUUID(UUID.randomUUID()/*UUID.fromString(String.valueOf(e.getMessage()).replace("UUID: ", ""))*/);
        } else if (String.valueOf(e).contains("GameUUIDs")) {
            // TODO: Make UUID parser for this
            MecaCoreConnector.getMecaConnection().getUserData().setGameUUIDs(new ArrayList<UUID>());
        } else if (String.valueOf(e).contains("AvatarLink")) {
            try {
                MecaCoreConnector.getMecaConnection().getUserData().setUserAvatar(getImage(String.valueOf(e).replace("AvatarLink ", "")));
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                Logger.logError(e1);
            }
        } else if (String.valueOf(e).contains("Rank")) {
            MecaCoreConnector.getMecaConnection().getUserData().setUserRank(String.valueOf(e).replace("Rank ", ""));
            MecaCoreConnector.getMecaConnection().getUserData().setUsername(LoginClient.getLoginClient().username.getText());
            LoginClient.getLoginClient().initDisplay();
        } else {
            Logger.logInfo(e);
        }
        if (String.valueOf(e).contains("fileCreate")) {
            createFile();
        }

        /*
         * Advertisments
         */
        if (String.valueOf(e).contains("advertSize")) {
            try {
                sortAdvertisments(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(e).replace("advertSize ", "")));
            } catch (NumberFormatException | MalformedURLException e1) {
                Logger.logError(e1);
            }
        }
        if (String.valueOf(e).contains("adImageURLs")) {
            imageURLs = String.valueOf(e).replace("adImageURLs ", "");
        }
        if (String.valueOf(e).contains("adImageLinks")) {
            imageLinks = String.valueOf(e).replace("adImageLinks ", "");
        }
        if (String.valueOf(e).contains("adImageViewChances")) {
            viewChances = String.valueOf(e).replace("adImageViewChances ", "");
        }

        /*
         * Games
         */

        if (String.valueOf(e).contains("gameUUIDs")) {

        }
        if (String.valueOf(e).contains("gameNames")) {

        }
        if (String.valueOf(e).contains("gameImageURLs")) {

        }
        if (String.valueOf(e).contains("gameBackgroundImageURLs")) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        Logger.logError(cause);
        ctx.close();
    }

    public void createFile() {

    }

    private Image getImage(String url) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
        con.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.76"); 
        InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
        Image img = ImageIO.read(in);
        return img;
    }

    private UUID[] parseUUIDs(String uuids) {
        String consUUID = "";
        UUID[] uuid = new UUID[uuids.length() / 36];
        for (int y = 0; y < uuid.length; y += 36) {
            consUUID = uuids.substring(y, y + 36);
            uuid[y] = UUID.fromString(consUUID);
        }
        return uuid;
    }

    private void sortAdvertisments(int size) throws MalformedURLException {
        ads = new Advertisment[size];
        for (int m = 0; m < size; m++) {
            Advertisment a = new Advertisment();
            a.getAd().setImageURL(new URL(getParsedArray(imageURLs)[m]));
            a.getAd().setImageLink(new URL(getParsedArray(imageLinks)[m]));
            a.getAd().setViewChance(Double.parseDouble(getParsedArray(viewChances)[m]));
            ads[m] = a;
        }
    }

    private Command getCommand(String message) {
        message = message.substring(0, message.indexOf(" "));
        return Command.valueOf(message);
    }

    private LoginDataType getLoginDataType(String message) {
        return LoginDataType.valueOf(message);
    }

    private DataType getDataType(String message) {
        return DataType.valueOf(message);
    }

    private String[] getParsedArray(String input) {
        return input.split(" ");
    }

    public static Advertisment[] getAdvertisments() {
        return ads;
    }

    public static MecaCoreConnectorAdapter getConnectionAdapter() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

ServerChannelHandler (Server):

```
import io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelOption;
import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel;
import io.netty.handler.codec.DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder;
import io.netty.handler.codec.Delimiters;
import io.netty.handler.codec.string.StringDecoder;
import io.netty.handler.codec.string.StringEncoder;
import net.meca.server.lib.Reference;

public class ServerChannelHandler  {

    /**
     * Initialize the Server Channel Handler
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */

    public static void init() throws InterruptedException {
        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();

            b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup);

            b.channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class);

            b.childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                 @Override
                 public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                     ch.pipeline().addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
                     ch.pipeline().addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder());
                     ch.pipeline().addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());
                     ch.pipeline().addLast("handler", new ServerChannelHandlerAdapter());
                 }
             });

             b.option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128);
             b.childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

            ChannelFuture f = b.bind(Reference.port).sync();
            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
```

ServerChannelHandlerAdapter (Server):

```
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.UUID;

import net.meca.server.lib.BufferedUtils;
import net.meca.server.lib.Reference;
import net.meca.server.logger.Logger;

public class ServerChannelHandlerAdapter extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void channelRegistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        Logger.logInfo("Connected: " + ctx.channel());
        ctx.channel().write("Connected to MecaCore V" + Reference.version + "\n\r");
        ctx.channel().flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object e) throws Exception {
        Logger.logInfo(e);
        /*
         * Responses
         */
        if (String.valueOf(e).contains("Username:") && String.valueOf(e).contains("Password:")) {
            Logger.logInfo("Searching for UserData for " + e);
            int splitPoint = processString(String.valueOf(e).replace("Username:", "").replace("Password:", ""));
            String parsedUser = String.valueOf(e).replace("Username:", "").replace("Password:", "").substring(0, splitPoint);

            String parsedPass = String.valueOf(e).replace("Username:", "").replace("Password:", "").substring(splitPoint, String.valueOf(e).replace("Username:", "").replace("Password:", "").replace(" ", "").length() + 1).replace(" ", "");
            if (new File(MecaCore.getInstance().getProgramPath() + "UserData" + File.separator + parsedUser + File.separator + parsedPass).exists()) {
                ctx.channel().writeAndFlush("Login Details Valid, Logging in...");
                username = parsedUser;
                password = parsedPass;
            }
        } else {
            ctx.channel().write("[MecaCore] Login is Invalid!\n\r");
            return;
        }

        if (username != null && password != null) {
            try {
                fetchUserData(username, password);
                ctx.channel().write("\r\n" + "createUser" + "\r\n");
                ctx.channel().write("NumericID " + String.valueOf(numericID) + "\r\n");
                ctx.channel().write("UUID " + String.valueOf(uuid) + "\r\n");
                ctx.channel().write("GameUUIDs " + String.valueOf(gameUUIDs) + "\r\n");
                ctx.channel().write("AvatarLink " + String.valueOf(avatarLink) + "\r\n");
                ctx.channel().write("Rank " + String.valueOf(rank) + "\r\n");
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                Logger.logError(e1);
            }
        } else {
            Logger.logInfo("No Permission to access Server! Disconnecting...");
            ctx.write("No Permission to access Server! Disconnecting...");
            ctx.channel().disconnect();
            return;
        }
        ctx.channel().flush();
    }

    private String username;
    private String password;

    private String numericID;
    private UUID uuid;
    private String gameUUIDs;
    private String avatarLink;
    private String rank;

    private int processString(String replace) {
        return replace.indexOf(" ");
    }

    private void fetchUserData(String username, String password) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
        String[] info = BufferedUtils.readFile(MecaCore.getInstance().getProgramPath() + "UserData" + File.separator + username + File.separator + password, 5);
        numericID = info[0];
        uuid = UUID.fromString(info[1]);
        gameUUIDs = info[2];
        avatarLink = info[3];
        rank = info[4];
    }
}
```

I also get this error when the client is forcefully disconnected from the server by shutting down the application forcefully

```
    Sep 22, 2014 9:07:37 PM io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext exceptionCaught
WARNING: An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:375)
        at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:446)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:881)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:225)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I simply do not know how to make it stop freezing the client/server and i need help with this problem

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The Editor deleted the bottom part of the question :/

Comment: Ah, I've made an edit that should display the stack trace seperately from the last code block ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call flush() at some point to flush the data on the channel, otherwise it will just sit in the outbound queue. So for a "quick" fix replace write(...) with writeAndFlush(...). You may want to think about a smarter way to not flush too often thought.

Comment: Iv tried multiple methods of flushing the data and it still seems to do the same so im not sure if it is that but thanks for advising me to get rid of the data

Comment: Is there any know problems with Java 8 Update 11 and Netty 4.0?

Comment: I have updated the code so there is a lot new that may help with your answer to my problem :)

Comment: @TheCheatgamer1 - I am also facing the same issue when there is forceful disconnection between client and server . Were you able to fix the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use [Hercules](http://www.hw-group.com/products/hercules/index_es.html) to test your application separately, Hercules provides functions of client and server separately. Then you can discard who is the problem, the client or the server.

Hope this help.

Comment: Iv already made a api to record every byte that is transferred in and out of my applications but thanks :)